# With rails, how do I find objects NOT in a Has Many Through collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say an article has many tags through taggings.

```
Article
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, :though :taggings
end
```

@article.tags #gives all the tags for that article

How do I find all the tags that this article does NOT have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this using Rails finders would be to do two queries and subtract:

```
class Article
  def unused_tags
    Tag.all - self.tags
  end
end
```

Alternately, you could do this through SQL (which would be more efficient since you'd be only getting rows that you *want*):

```
query = <<-eos
SELECT *
FROM tags AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM taggings
  WHERE article_id = ?
    AND tag_id = t.id
)
eos
Tag.find_by_sql [query, article.id]
```

Comment: I used this approach as part of a collection_select, so my code looked like Tag.all - @instance_article.tags

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
 class Article
    def missing_tags
       Tag.find(:all, :conditions => ['id NOT IN (SELECT taggings.tag_id FROM taggings WHERE (taggings.article_id = ?))', self.id])
    end
 end
```

@article.missing_tags